# Get user google account picture from email address

Tags: android, gmail

I have list of email ids' of users that I get from calendar like

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#event",
  "etag": "\"zDYNyduc5vEaXlXz7scQOpE_a8Y/MTM3MjA4MTk2MjYwNDAwMA\"",
  "id": "9r48ao9snfaotnao2r82kpjvh4",
  "status": "confirmed",
  "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=OXI0OGFvOXNuZmFvdG5hbzJyODJrcGp2aDQgMXJzMGZlYXNsaXY4Z3VkNTE5aGlybXVvamdAZw",
  "created": "2013-06-24T13:52:42.000Z",
  "updated": "2013-06-24T13:52:42.604Z",
  "summary": "Arsenal v Southampton",
  "location": " \tEmirates Stadium",
  "creator": {
    "email": "premiercalendar@gmail.com",
    "displayName": "Premier League"
  },
  "organizer": {
    "email": "1rs0feasliv8gud519hirmuojg@group.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "Premier League",
    "self": true
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2013-11-23T16:00:00+01:00"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2013-11-23T17:45:00+01:00"
  },
  "iCalUID": "9r48ao9snfaotnao2r82kpjvh4@google.com",
  "sequence": 0
},
```

here I have `creator email address` and I have lot of such records for each event on my calendar

Now, I need to fetch user picture from email address like `premiercalendar@gmail.com`

**Update :** Is it possible to get this without any `oauth` authentication?

**update 2 :** I found that for facebook I can get user picture with following url

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=email@example.com&type=user
```

but along with access token 
any similar approach for **g+**

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can get user public details from the XML link...

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/<paste_google_username>
```

and You can easily get it like this...

```
    int start = xml.indexOf("<media:thumbnail url='");
    String urlPart = xml.substring(start);
    thumbnail_url = (String) urlPart
                                .subSequence(urlPart.indexOf("http"),
                                        urlPart.indexOf("'/>"));
    Log.d("picture321", thumbnail_url);

    HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(URI.create(thumbnail_url));
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = null;

    try {
        response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufHttpEntity.getContent());
        httpRequest.abort();


        } 
       catch (ClientProtocolException el) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        el.printStackTrace();
        } 
       catch (IOException el) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        el.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I have email address of user. is there again any way to get user name from that?

Comment: Yes, There is way, from that xml url, u can search for title tag <titlt>name_of_user</title>

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no possibility to get details of a person with their email, but using Google OAuth, you can get email and all additional details of the person.

see here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/